# Is there a more efficient way to Google search by image instead of dragging?

Tags: google-image-search

Google has released their search by image functionality and I tend to use it a lot. The problem lies with a quicker way to search than dragging or pasting the URL.

Ideally I would like an extension that I can right click on the image and search immediately without the two step issue.

Comment: I didn't know Google had released this. Awesome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an extension for Chrome called [Search by Image](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm#) which is provided by Google. This allows you to right click an image and initiate a Google Search.

[image: Image icon]

[image]